# npm Incompatible with OSX Frameworks?

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, npm, frameworks

I have a git repo that is used as an npm package. The package.json specifies a folder containing an OSX framework:

- Package

  - SDK.framework

    - Headers (folder alias to Versions/Current/Headers)
    - Versions

When I commit this to git, the "Headers" folder alias is present in the repo, as a tiny file, with contents like "Versions/Current/Headers"

When I install the package using "npm install", the folder aliases are not downloaded from the git repo, it seems. If I look in my node_modules folder, it appears that npm simply decided to not download the alias files.

How does npm decide to avoid/ignore those files? It is an OSX folder alias, but it is also just a tiny file with a single string in it. As far as I know, I have no ignore settings that would stop these files from being included in the package.

I realize this isn't the primary usage for npm, but it has been a helpful tool for Unity 3D game development packages.

I was surprised that it chooses to ignore these files, and I'm mainly wondering if this is some limitation of "npm" or it should work, but something is misconfigured on my end? I never saw anything saying "npm automatically ignores folder or file aliases".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up on this, I didn't find a solution for dealing with aliases in npm. To workaround this issue, I had to replace the aliases with the actual files. For my purposes, this is fine.

As a result, the alias "Headers" was removed and the contents of "Versions/Current/Headers" were simply copied to a folder called "Headers". This removes the alias usage entirely, and I'm able to use the Framework through npm as a result.

Not the ideal solution, but a solution nonetheless.